# Enumerate and label sequences of 1's and 0's with fixed number of 1's

Tags: combinatorics

Let us consider the space, $\mathcal{S},$ of sequences of 1's and 0's of length $N$ with exactly $k$ 1's. There are $\binom{N}{k}$ of such sequences. I want to find a simple arithmetic bijective function mapping $\mathcal{S}$ to $\{1,2,...,\binom{N}{k}  \}$,
$$ F: \mathcal{S} \rightarrow \{1,2,...,\binom{N}{k}  \}. $$

With a ''simple arithmetic'' function I mean one that only involves elementary arithmetic operations and that has lower complexity than a search algorithm over the whole space $\mathcal{S}.$
To clarify, let me give an example with $N=4$ and $k=2.$ The sequences in $\mathcal{S}$ are

$$0 0 1 1$$
$$0 1 0 1$$
$$1 0 0 1$$
$$0 1 1 0$$
$$1 0 1 0$$
$$1 1 0 0$$
With this particular ordering, what we want is a function $F$ mapping $[0 0 1 1]$ to 1, $[0 1 0 1]$ to 2, etc ($F([ 0 0 1 1]) = 1,F([ 0 1 0 1]) = 2,... $).

My first idea was to look at the sequences as numbers in binary format, $\sum_{i=1}^{N} a_i 2^{i-1}.$ It then looks relatively easy, but the function ''convert to decimal'' maps $\mathcal{S}$ to a set of non-consecutive natural numbers.

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4198557/177399

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this recursively: either the first bit is $1$ or the first bit is $0$. We're going to order the strings using the numeric base-2 order. Thus every string starting with a $1$ has a higher value than the ones starting with a $0$.

There are $\binom{n-1}{k}$ strings where the first bit is $0$. Therefore, if the first bit is $1$ then $F(S) > \binom{n-1}{k}$. And actually, if $S'$ is the tail, then $F_k(S) = \binom{n-1}{k} + F_{k-1}(S')$.

So we get the following algorithm:

Let $n_0 > n_1 > \dots > n_{k - 1}$ be the positions of the $1$s in $S$ where the highest bit is position $n$ and the lowest bit is position $1$. Then

$$F_k(S) = \sum_{i = 0}^k \binom{n_i - 1}{k - i}$$

Or you could use the recursive algorithm $F_k(S) = \binom{m-1}{k} + F_{k-1}(S')$ where $m$ is the position of the first $1$ in $S$.

Note: the output of $F_k$ starts at $0$ rather than $1$.