# Problem on correspondence between one number and an array

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

Consider an array of length 100 which contains 20 many 1, 20 many 2 $\&$ 60 many 3. It is clear number of such array is $N=\dbinom{100}{20,20,60}$. I want to find a one to one correspondence between one number $i \in [1,N]$ and one such array.

Comment: What have you tried?  What would you do if there were only 2 rather than 3 values?

Comment: For 2 case, we can get idea from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system

Comment: So do a similar thing with the locations of 1s vs the rest, and then among the rest between the 2s vs the 3s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\binom{100}{20,20,60}=\binom{100}{20}\cdot \binom{80}{20}$, because in order to choose a sequence of $20$ ones, $20$ twos, and $60$ threes, you can choose the locations of the ones in $\binom{100}{20}$ ways, then choose the locations of the twos from the remaining $80$ spaces in $\binom{80}{20}$ ways.

Let $N=\binom{100}{20,20,60}$, let $M_1=\binom{100}{20}$, and let $M_2=\binom{80}{20}$, so that $N=M_1\cdot M_2$. It sufficies to find a pair of correspondences, where

1. The first correspondence is between size-$20$ subsets of $\{1,\dots,100\}$ and the range $\{0,\dots,M_1-1\}$,
2. The second correspondence is between size-$20$ subsets of $\{1,\dots,80\}$ and the range $\{0,\dots,M_2-1\}$.

Once you have both of these correspondences, here is how you solve the whole problem. Given a number $i$ between $0$ and $N-1$, we can uniquely write $i$ as
$
i = j\cdot M_1+k$, for numbers $j$ between $0$ and $M_1-1$ and $k$ between $0$ and $M_2-1$. Explicitly,
$$j=\lfloor i/M_1\rfloor\qquad k=i\,\%\,M_1$$ where $a\,\%\,b$ is the remainder of $a$ divided by $b$. Then, use $j$ to determine a size $20$ subset of $\{1,\dots,100\}$ via the first correspondence, giving the locations of the ones, then use $k$ to construct a size $20$ subset of $\{1,\dots,80\}$ via the second correspondence, giving the locations of the twos.

Therefore, we can reduce the three-number problem to two instances of the two-number problem, both of which are solved with [combinadics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system). I gave a description of this indexing function in [this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4198557/indexing-function/4198581#4198581).